# Ignore some class in train

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I'm using tensor-flow models object detection for my use case, and I have some boxes/classes that I would like to ignore in the training process because the quality of them is not the best.
I don't want to delete the boxes area with black rectangle because that will change the image 
and I don't want them to be a Negative example in the training process

Is there an easy way to do that?
I'm using tensorflow models object detection faster-RCNN implementation with PASCAL VOC data presentation

Comment: You could mark them as "difficult" boxes (there's a field for that in the VOC format), I think they will be handled differently (possibly not at all) during training and evaluation; unfortunately I can't find how they're handled exactly right now...

Comment: I saw the ```difficult``` variable, from my understanding for the training its just remove the object so this area can be pick as negative 
and for evaluation when you want to check your performance without changing the tf-record